# If I accidentally agree for new WhatsApp's terms and conditions, How to revert that?

Tags: privacy, police

WhatsApp team updates their policy and it will be from Feb 8. I accidentally agreed with the policy. Later I realized the policy is not good.

**How can I revert my agreement with the WhatsApp team?**

We have alternatives like Signal and telegram but I like to use WhatsApp. I am thinking if most of us not agree with WhatsApp's policy then they will change their decision.

Answer (score 3):

### Don’t use WhatsApp

The terms of service are the contract that WhatsApp are willing to make their service available under. You have 2 choices:

- accept those terms and use the service,
- reject the terms and don’t use the service.

There is a theoretical 3rd choice but it’s not practically feasible: negotiate with WhatsApp for your own custom terms. It’s not feasible because WhatsApp have to be willing to do that, and they aren’t for the very simple reason that they can’t administratively deal with individual contracts with millions of users.

### More generally

You can’t *accidentally* agree to a contract. Entering a contract requires a deliberate intention by all parties.

WhatsApp showed their intention by providing the service and the terms. You showed your intention by clicking “I agree”. The instant you did that the contract became binding on both of you.

You can’t go back later and say “Whoops! I didn’t mean it.” You did it, you meant it. If it was a mistake it’s your mistake and you get the consequences of your mistake.

Comment: "Entering a contract requires a deliberate intention by all parties." This is completely incompatible with the fact that nobody reads the EULA. -1, at least until I see a source that debunks the common belief that EULAs are unenforcable.

Comment: "You can’t accidentally agree to a contract." - Sure you can, even if that's not what happened here. On a phone it's perfectly possible to hit the wrong thing.

Comment: @Studoku https://law.stackexchange.com/q/3330/344

Comment: @DM there could be an argument in that case but ticking an “I agree” button, completing a captcha and confirming? Not so much.

Comment: In my case, I agree it wasn't accidental. But I do feel I was mislead. There was a big button to accept in the middle and I missed the small "x" at the top. Sure they are both visible, but there should have been "accept" and "not accept" at the bottom like a normal terms. [Terms screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXZtS.jpg)